# Problem with socket connection by using computer name?

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I want to connect my cell-phone to PC by using socket connection.

But it's only successful when I use IP Address. I try to use Computer Name but it throws `UnKnowHostException`.

```
mySocket = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 10000); //it's ok!

mySocket = new Socket("My_PC_NAME", 10000); //it throw UnKnowHostException !
```

My cell phone is using WIFI and its IP is : 192.168.1.99

Please help me, 
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This is quite normal as your android device hasn't access to the DNS that assigns names to IP addresses. Since it isn't part of your PC network, you can't use computer names for the socket connection.

Comment: @kgiannakais it's not possible in android or also not possible in java?

Comment: Thank you ! But do you have any way to can connect by using computer name?

Comment: In desktop java it should be possible to use computer names. I don't think that it is possible for an Android device to be part of a windows network for example.

Comment: @user820212: You need to have a mapping between IPs and computer names. This is usually what a DNS gateway does. Perhaps you could save the mapping as a preference and allow the user to edit it.